# Customize System/Navigation Bar without root on Android

Tags: android

Is it at all possible? We want to put non-button Views in our System Bar. We do have system keys for our specific tablet.

One of my friends tried doing it with no success, but I assume he was looking in the wrong places. I don't know what he knows about the process, so I can't say what we've tried.

We're using Android 4.2 on a 10" tablet.

I guess I should also mention that we've tried this app - https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.cygery.customnavbar.demo though we haven't been able to find any info on how he got it to work.